# How does the the line after the javascript popupwindow works?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

OK I have a method from the code behind that creates a popupwindow. Then there's a line of code that executes after that Im wondering when does that line of code executes, If it executes after using the popupwindow or right after it creates the popupwindow?
EX:

```
void exPopupWindowMethod()
{
string scr = "window.open('examplePopup.aspx','popup_window',.....);";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", scr, true);
}

String example = "example"; //initialization  
exPopupWindowMethod();// the method that creates the popup window
example=null;
```

I dont know if theres a duplicate question for this but pls consider my question. I need to clarify this for using of sessions thanks!

Comment: The code for `exPopupWindowMethod()` would be nice.

Comment: @MikkoViitala pls see edit tnx!

Comment: You're talking about when the `example=null` line executes?

Comment: @jasonscript yes sir im just wondering about that..

Comment: @jasonscript im using it for session purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `example=null` line will be executed immediately (i.e. before the popup window is shown).

The reason for this is that the `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` wraps the code in a `document.ready` loop which will wait until the rest of the page has completed loading before executing.

Because the `example=null` line isn't waiting for the rest of the DOM to load, it will execute immediately.

[ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the code after the popup with something like : `Response.Write("Test");`
And check if the response is done while or after the popup shows?